# NuGet: Adding documentation to a package

Tags: nuget

Is there any convention for adding help files (mshc) to NuGet packages?

Answer (score 4):

No, there's nothing in nuget for doc files. We recommend setting a project page and adding content there. (That doesn't help the offline help scenario thought). If you feel strongly about packaging documentation with your package then open a bug on [GitHub](https://github.com/NuGet/Home)