# Adding file to nuget package

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I would like to add a `chm` file (documentation) to my nuget package. Is that possible? I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114921/nuget-adding-documentation-to-a-package), but it's from 2011 and I wonder if anything has changed since then.

If it's possible, I'd like to know how to do it through Visual Studio. My nuget package gets created by msbuild directly from the `csproj` file (from which an intermediate `nuspec` file gets created).

I noticed that if I add this line in the intermediate nuspec file

```
<file src="Content\**" target="content" />
```

and build the package, the chm file does get added to the package, but I don't know how to view it after I install the package in another solution. Is it possible?

Comment: Hi, per this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#including-content-files and Content files are immutable files that a package needs to include in a project, you can have a try with your shared config and publish this package, it should works as your expected.

Comment: @SaraLiu-MSFT Thank you for the reference. You're right, the file does get added to the package and is displayed. The `<file src="Content\**" target="content" />` in nuspec did the work for me. However, I am not sure how to specify this file in the original csproj file.

Comment: The change I needed to make in my csproj file was adding this line: `  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="content/*.*" target="Content"></Content>
  </ItemGroup>` . My documentation is located in a `content` folder which is in the same folder as the `csproj`

Comment: Hi, you can have a try with <Content Include="xxxx">
 <Pack>true</Pack>
</Content>, by default everything of type "Content" gets included in the package, for more detail information, please check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#pack-scenarios, since with the PackageReference format, NuGet 4.0+ can store all manifest metadata directly within a project file rather than using a separate .nuspec file, you need consider use the PackageReference format.